# How commons dbcp (and other connection pools) manage open statements and resultsets?

Tags: memory-management, jdbc, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

Specifically, when I return a connection to the pool, does dbcp (and other connection pools) close the statements and resultsets for me?

Or should I be closing these myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I see that statements are closed by dbcp in DelegatingConnection.passivate() and DelegatingStatement.close() closes the resultsets.